# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object regex

Tags: python, regex, preprocessor

Proses 1

````r
all_data_article['title']=[r.sub( '', s) for s in all_data_article['title'].tolist()]
all_data_article['url']=[r.sub( '', str(s)) for s in all_data_article['url'].tolist()]
all_data_article.head()```
````

Proses 2

```
all_data_title= all_data_article['title'].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
print(all_data_title)
```

Proses 3

```
all_data_title[1].str.lower()
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')

f = open("tala-stopwords-idn.txt", "r")
stopword_list = []
for line in f:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    line_list = stripped_line.split()
    stopword_list.append(line_list[0])
f.close()

len(stopword_list)

data_article = []
data_article = all_data_title[1].str.lower()
print(data_article)
```

the error comes from the link I entered into the table and did the processing on the regex, but when I continued to the next process I experienced an error like the code below the error is actually in the process

```
results_token = []
for sentence in data_article:
    results_token.append(word_tokenize(sentence))
```

Error Massage

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-f435928e3594> in <module>
      1 results_token = []
      2 for sentence in data_article:
----> 3     results_token.append(word_tokenize(sentence))

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py in _match_potential_end_contexts(self, text)
   1373         before_words = {}
   1374         matches = []
-> 1375         for match in reversed(list(self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text))):
   1376             # Ignore matches that have already been captured by matches to the right of this match
   1377             if matches and match.end() > before_start:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Add `print(sentence)` to the for loop to see what you are sending to word_tokenize

Comment: @tdelaney when done `print(sentence)`  it says none

Comment: @tdalaney before `all_data article['url']=[r.substr(s)) for s in all_data_article['url'].tolist()]`
i use `all_data_article['author']=[r.sub( ''", s)) for s in all_data_article['author'].tolist()]`

but when i change from author to url the error will occur